# aws-cli error when using an array on bash script

Tags: linux, bash, aws-cli

I've been trying create a script that reboot failing ec2 instances, however it gives me an error like:

```
A client error (InvalidCharacter) occurred when calling the RebootInstances operation: Your request contains an invalid XML character and can not be processed
```

I'm creating an array of the failing ec2 instances ids and then passing to aws-cli to the work

```
if [ ${#instances_to_reboot[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "rebooting instances"
    aws ec2 reboot-instances --instance-ids $(echo ${instances_to_reboot[@]}) --dry-run
else
    echo "no instances to reboot"
fi
```

I've notice that if use

```
aws ec2 reboot-instances --instance-ids $(echo ${instances[@]}) --dry-run
```

on the terminal, it works.. so I don't what I'm doing wrong

Comment: If you swap out the aws command with just the echo, what is the result?

Comment: you mean like `aws ec2 reboot-instances --instance-ids $(echo $instances) --dry-run` ? it will only print instances[0] and it gives me the same error

Comment: No, I mean what is printed when you do `echo ${instances_to_reboot[@]}` at that exact point in your script.

Comment: it prints something like `i-8d5ef1d1 i-78febaed i-d20b4e78`

Comment: Hmmm.... If you append `--debug` to the command it will print out debug logs. As part of that, it should print the parameters sent over the wire and what the cli receives. When scrubbing that, please do not alter any non-alphanumeric characters. I have a feeling that a long dash is being sent.

Comment: still in the same issue, I've notice that if I redirect stdout to a file the intances id show like this: `"^[[36mi-0f89ce85^[[0m ^[[36mi-7465ecf8^[[0m ^[[36mi-b379513b^[[0m"`

Comment: Your array contains ASCII escape sequences. ASCI escape sequence `ESC[36m` is light blue I believe in terminal colors and `ESC[0m` is color reset. When you assign those values to the array, make sure it is in plain text and not attempting to use terminal capabilities. As a test, if you `echo -e ${instances[@]}`, you will see that the colors will change on a supported terminal.

Comment: A quick solution is to `sed` out those escape sequences `aws ec2 reboot-instances --instance-ids $(echo ${instances_to_reboot[@]} | sed $'s/\033[[0-9]\+m//g') --dry-run`.

Comment: it didn't work @alvits but you're right is there any way just to avoid this? I don't know if by changing the charset or something cause I notice is us-ascii

Comment: It worked on my test. The tool you used to generate the instance id, which is subsequently assigned to array, generated the escape sequence. The tool may have been compiled against `ncurse` and uses terminal capability. Check the documentation of the tool to see if it support disabling colors or disabling `tty`. Most modern tools allow disabling/enabling colors and they usually come with scripts that are installed in `/etc/profile.d/`.

Comment: Checkout this [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html) from Amazon where you can control output.

Comment: it worked! the tool I'm using is awslogs to get the logs from cloudwatch, I read the code and the guy has an option not specified on the README file to disable this --no-color :) thanks man!